# Decompose bipartite graph by integer flow

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Given a bipartite graph $G$ with sides $A,B$.

A method to decompose the edge-set of $G$ into two subgraphs $G_1,G_2$ subject to some constraints is to add two extra vertices, direct the edges from $A$ to $B$, and allow the flows on these edges to be at least 0 and at most 1. If the other constraints on the flow are integral and satisfy Kirchhoff's condition, then there is an integer flow.
Then one takes the edges with flow 0 as $G_1$ and edges with flow $1$ as $G_2$.
For example, like this [one](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/net.3230230303)

Is this a mature area? What if one wants to decompose $G$ into three, or even $k$ subgraphs? What do they often set on the constraints?